# HVAC: Nest - Yet another 'C' wire question

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, nest, transformer

I have a dual transformer system. At the AC/Blower unit, there are 'R_c', 'Y' and 'G' wires; there's 0VAC between the 'Y' and 'G' wires, and each shows 27VAC to the 'R_c' wire.

At the boiler, there are 'R_h' and 'W' wires, with 27VAC between the two.

Nest reports "N72 error: No equipment detected" on 'R_h', but heat is working fine.

The boiler is connected to my standby generator. When we lose power, the AC/Blower goes dark, and Nest suddenly reports it is unable to detect an HVAC system. The stat won't even let me navigate away to the heat menu, and quickly drains its battery. I'm wondering what my options are for using the Nest for heat during a power outage. I can run a 'C' wire up from the boiler, but my understanding is Nest (ridiculously) insists that the 'C' come from cooling. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've edited your post to be clearer; please make sure it's still what you meant. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are you open to getting a different thermostat? What make and model are the air-handler and furnace involved? Why do you have a separate air-handler and furnace, even?

Comment: I apologize - I meant to say boiler rather than furnace. Unfortunately I already have 2 Nests connected so it would be a pricey change. The air handler is relatively new, while the boiler is likely early 90's - converted to natural gas from oil.

Comment: The air handler is a Ruud RCHL-48A1G.

Comment: I take it the air-handler is merely one hydronic zone out of several, no?

Comment: It seems the air handler is strictly for cooling. The boiler has 3 Honeywell r845a relays on it, with the nests connected to the TT terminals.

Comment: Are all three Nests connected to their own air handlers on the cooling side, or are the other two heat-only?

Comment: 2 Nests are connected to separate air handlers for cooling. Each Nest is also connected to a separate boiler relay. The third boiler relay has an old stat on it.

Comment: Are both sets of wires (boiler and air-handler) routed directly to the thermostat location?  Or is there only a single cable running to each thermostat...?

Comment: Yes, W and R_h from boiler, and Y, G and R_c from air-handler.